# Angular2+ не рендерится модалка с iframe, пока не двинется мышь

Tags: angular, iframe, popup

Всем привет, Такая проблема:
Angular, есть компонент (модалка) - кредитная карта. Есть сервис, который запускает библиотеку (платёжная система, получает пропсы, генерирует токен, устанавливает соединение с api, генерирует html-страницу в iframe).
Ответ с подтверждением оплат и OTP-ключем приходит в iframe, который лежит в отдельной модалке.
Эта модалка не запускается, пока пользователь не сделает что-то в браузере, тоже самое и после свершения платежей - окно автоматически должно закрываться, но пока пользователь не шевельнется - все остается статичным.
модалка iframe.html

```
<iframe name="authentication-3ds-frame" id="xendit-three-ds-container"style="width: 100%; height: 370px;" ></iframe>
```

модалка iframe.ts

```
export class Authentication3DSComponent {
    @Input() modalData: any;
    globalEventsSubscription;

    constructor(
      private eventService: EventService, private modal: Modal) {
        this.globalEventsSubscription = this.eventService.emitter.subscribe(
            (event) => {
                this.handleGlobalEvents(event);
            }
        );
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        let payer_authentication_url = this.modalData.payer_authentication_url;
        window.open(payer_authentication_url, "authentication-3ds-frame");
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.globalEventsSubscription.unsubscribe();
    }

    handleGlobalEvents(event) {
        if (event.type === 'payment-service:xendit-token-status-verified') {
            this.close();
        }
    }

    close() {
        this.modal.close({
            id: "Authentication3DS"
        })
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

вопрос решен отключением zone.js и "ручным" запуском ChangeDetection в интервале 100мс